# R web scraping by a certain option value

Tags: r, web, screen-scraping

I'm new to r and web scraping and I was trying to **scrape** this page https://tools.canlearn.ca/cslgs-scpse/cln-cln/reea-mdl/reea-mdl-1-eng.do?nom-name=AB

It includes 3 option values 10, 25 and "all". How can I scrape the table when I choose "all"? Can anyone take a look and share some insight? Thank you!

Comment: Please include your current coding attempt and explain what isn't working. There is guidance on asking a question on StackOverflow to help you elicit  answers helpful to yourself + the site. See: [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the tips @QHarr! It turns out the `option` doesn't make any AJAX call at all and the web page actually includes all the table content.

Comment: That is good news.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach. With this approach, we click on the next button to get all the tables instead of selecting "all" :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://tools.canlearn.ca/cslgs-scpse/cln-cln/reea-mdl/reea-mdl-1-eng.do?nom-name=AB"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()

clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)

list_Tables <- list()

for(i in 1 : 3)
{
  html_Content <- doc$documentElement()$innerHtml()
  list_Tables[[i]] <- (read_html(html_Content) %>% html_table())[[1]]
  web_Obj <- doc$querySelector("#wb-auto-4_next")
  web_Obj$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
}

list_Tables[[1]]
   EI Code                     EI Name        EI Type
1     BJAB           Burman University Junior College
2     BJAC   Northwestern Polytechnic. Junior College
3     BJAD    Grant Macewan University Junior College
4     BJAF          Lethbridge College Junior College
5     BJAG      Mount Royal University Junior College
6     BJAH        Red Deer Polytechnic Junior College
7     BJAI        Medicine Hat College Junior College
8     BJAK Concordia Lutheran Seminary Junior College
9     BJAP          Bow Valley College Junior College
10    BJAQ            Norquest College Junior College
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Address
1                                                                                                                                                                                 6730 University Drive,\n                \n              \n              \n              \n              \n                \n                  Lacombe,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  (403) 782-3381
2                                                                                                                                                                             10726 - 106th Ave.,\n                \n              \n              \n              \n              \n                \n                  Grande Prairie,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  (780) 539-2911
3  Financial Services,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  P.O. Box 1796,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  10700 - 104 Avenue,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Edmonton,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  (780) 497-4304
4                                                                                                                                                                             3000 College Dr. South,\n                \n              \n              \n              \n              \n                \n                  Lethbridge,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  (403) 320-3372
5                                                                                     MRU Fees Office,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  4825 Mount Royal, Gate SW,\n                \n              \n              \n              \n                \n                  Calgary,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  (403) 440-6306
6          Access Centre,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  100 College Boulevard,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  PO Box 5005,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Red Deer,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  4033423300
7                                                                                                                                                                             299 College Dr. S.E.,\n                \n              \n              \n              \n              \n                \n                  Medicine Hat,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  (403) 529-3819
8                                                                                                                                                                                       7040 Ada Blvd.,\n                \n              \n              \n              \n              \n                \n                  Edmonton,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  (403) 479-8481
9                                                                                                                                                                                    345 6th Avenue SE ,\n                \n              \n              \n              \n              \n                \n                  Calgary,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  (403) 410-1400
10                                                                                                                                                                                      10215 - 108 Street,\n                \n              \n              \n              \n              \n                \n                  Edmonton,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Alberta,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  Canada,\n                \n              \n              \n                \n                  7804222020
   EI Designation Date
1           1988-12-21
2           1988-12-21
3           1988-12-21
4           1988-12-21
5           1988-12-21
6           1988-12-21
7           1988-12-21
8           1988-12-21
9           1988-12-21
10          1988-12-21
```